# Black and White film with cars in tunnels which were flooded

Tags: story-identification

A long time ago, the possibly early 80s I remember seeing a film, it was black and white, from my memory the cars in it were quite old fashioned to 40/50s style cars.

I believe the characters were in an undersea base or tunnel. They were trying to escape from flooding. I remember flood doors being closed and water rushing in with the characters trying to escape.

I remember there being futuristic (from the point of view of the film) elements, with electric valves etc.

The tunnels were not round, floors and walls were all vertical.

That is about all I can remember, but any specific questions may jog my memory.

Answer (score 3):

"Transatlantic Tunnel"(1935)?

It has a tunnel which isn't round in shape, it's Black & White, and looks somewhat futuristic for 1935 because it takes place in the near future of that time. IMDb page below.

Transatlantic Tunnel
http://imdb.com/rg/an_share/title/title/tt0027131/

Here is the full movie from YouTube. You said there was no flooding, but there is a flooding type scene at 1:12:00. It's volcanic steam, I believe, not water, and a supervisor doesnt want to seal off the level because his son might get trapped.

Comment: I thought this may have been it. But there are no cars or flooding in it. Good find all the same.

Comment: @Jeremy French. I uploaded the movie for you to watch. There was a flooding scene, but not water, and there were cars in the movie that did look futuristic. If this still isn't the one I will keep searching.

Comment: thanks, I checked it out, it's not the film I am thinking about, it seems too high a budget.

Comment: However apparently it is based on a book, of which 4 different films were made, so it could have been one of the others.